# addEventListener: listener cannot be nil:nil

Tags: lua, listener, addeventlistener, coronasdk, solar2d

I'm creating a new game with Coronasdk, I need to make trees appear from the right of the screen and make them scroll to the left.
That's the code

```
      local Trees = {}  --I generate trees that appears randomly
local function createTree(event)
table.insert(Trees, tree)
return tree
end

local function treeScroll (self, event)
  self.x = self.x - 3
end

MIN = 3000
MAX = 7000
local function gameLoop()
  local tree = createTree()
  tree.enterFrame = treeScroll
  Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", tree)
  for i, thisTree in ipairs (Trees) do
    if thisTree.x < -100 then
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", thisTree)
      display.remove (thisTree)
      table.remove (Trees, i)
    end
  end
  timer.cancel(timer1)
  timer1=timer.performWithDelay(math.random(MIN, MAX), gameLoop, 0)
end

timer1 = timer.performWithDelay (math.random(MIN, MAX), gameLoop, 0)
```

It tells me that addEventListener:Listener cannot be nil:nil, and it refers to this part

```
local function gameLoop()
  local tree = createTree()
  tree.enterFrame = treeScroll
  Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", tree)
  for i, thisTree in ipairs (Trees) do
    if thisTree.x < -100 then
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", thisTree)
      display.remove (thisTree)
      table.remove (Trees, i)
    end
  end
  timer.cancel(timer1)
  timer1=timer.performWithDelay(math.random(MIN, MAX), gameLoop, 0)
end
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: what is tree? you insert it into Trees in createTree. just from the posted code it appears to be a nil value. but you use it as if it were a table value. please share the definition of tree.

Comment: I had already declared the local tree at the beginning of the code, this is not the entire code but only the part where the error is

Comment: but from the provided code it is not obvious why you face that error nor do we know what tree actually is. providing more context, code and the quoted error message would help. don't you think?